# Anglar 16 MatTable trackBy on FormGoup to detect pristine fields

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, formgroups

I have a MatTable with a datasource composed of AbstractControls (FormGroups) for an editable table with action buttons at the end of the line to save or delete each element.

I would like to trackBy and check if the element is pristine or the value changes for the validation action button to be enabled or disabled.

This greatly improves rendering performances but any attempt at using a trackBy results in the action buttons disabled state not updating.

Here is an example of my try at implementing this behaviour.

```html
<ng-container [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ng-container formArrayName="myArray">
    <table
      [dataSource]="dataSource"
      [trackBy]="trackByControl"
      mat-table
    >

      ...


      <ng-container matColumnDef="aFormControl">
        <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell>
          A form field
        </th>
        <td *matCellDef="let element; let index = index" mat-cell>
          <mat-form-field [formGroupName]="index" appearance="outline">
            <input
              formControlName="aFormControl"
              matInput
              type="number"
            />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      ...

      <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
        <th *matHeaderCellDef aria-label="row actions" mat-header-cell>&nbsp; </th>
        <td *matCellDef="let element; let index = index" mat-cell>
          <button
            (click)="save(index)"
            [disabled]="isSaveDisabled(element)"
            color="primary"
            mat-icon-button
            type="button"
          >
            <mat-icon>check_circle</mat-icon>
          </button>

        ...

        </td>
      </ng-container>

      ...

    </table>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

```js
myForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  myArray: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({
      aFormControl: [1],
      anotherFormControl: [35]
    })
  ])
})

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<AbstractControl>(this.myForm?.get('myArray')?.controls)

save(index: number) {
  console.log('save')
}

isSaveDisabled(control: AbstractControl): boolean {
  const form = control as FormGroup
  return (
    form?.invalid ||
    (form?.controls?.['aFormControl']?.pristine &&
      form?.controls?.['anotherFormControl']?.pristine)
  )
}

trackByControl(index: number, control: AbstractControl): string {
  const form = control as FormGroup
  return (
      index.toString() +
      JSON.stringify(variantControl?.getRawValue()) +
      (
        form?.controls?.['aFormControl']?.pristine &&
        variantForm?.controls?.['anotherFormControl']?.pristine
      )?.toString()
    )
}
```

Regards.

Comment: To disabled you should pass as argument the "element", not the index: `[disabled]="isSaveDisabled(element)"`

Comment: Yes my bad, I'll update the example, I'm actually using the element

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able just to take your code and past it in stackblitz, but with some modification I have created [a running example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/4mwrbq?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.ts).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  // it works with out without changeDetection
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [
    MatTableModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['aFormControl', 'options'];
  formBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);

  myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    myArray: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        // added validator to check correct working
        aFormControl: [1, Validators.required],
        anotherFormControl: [35],
      }),
      this.formBuilder.group({
        aFormControl: [4, Validators.required],
        anotherFormControl: [3],
      }),
    ]),
  });

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<AbstractControl>(
    this.myForm.controls['myArray'].controls
  );

  save(index: number) {
    // Mark formGroup pristine
    this.myForm.get(`myArray.${index}`)?.markAsPristine();
  }

  isSaveDisabled(control: AbstractControl): boolean {
    // Simplified the code
    const { aFormControl, anotherFormControl } = (control as FormGroup)
      .controls;
    return (
      control.invalid || (aFormControl.pristine && anotherFormControl.pristine)
    );
  }

  trackByControl(index: number, control: AbstractControl): string {
    // It seems to me there's no effect on what I return. I can omit the `pristine`s it will work. 
    const { aFormControl, anotherFormControl } = (control as FormGroup)
      .controls;
    return `${index} ${aFormControl.pristine} ${anotherFormControl.pristine}`;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- No need for the containers, and us a form for a form... -->
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <table
    formArrayName="myArray"
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    [trackBy]="trackByControl"
    mat-table
  >
    <ng-container matColumnDef="aFormControl">
      <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell>A form field</th>
      <td
        *matCellDef="let element; let index = index"
        mat-cell
        [formGroupName]="index"
      >
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input formControlName="aFormControl" matInput type="number" />
        </mat-form-field>
        <!-- Just added the other input as well -->
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input formControlName="anotherFormControl" matInput type="number" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
      <th *matHeaderCellDef aria-label="row actions" mat-header-cell>&nbsp;</th>
      <td *matCellDef="let element; let index = index" mat-cell>
        <button
          (click)="save(index)"
          [disabled]="isSaveDisabled(element)"
          color="primary"
          mat-icon-button
          type="button"
        >
          <mat-icon>check_circle</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Everything works fine

Comment: This indeed works and allowed me to pinpoint my issue. I didn't think this would be where it would come from.

In the example I forgot to point out that the data used to generate the form actually comes from an @Input setter method that is triggered asynchronously, because the data displayed could change after an http call.

The method clears the form, fills the FormArray and replaces the dataSource.data.

After that the disabled state of the button is not updated anymore.

Would you happen to have any idea why that is ?

Comment: Could you reproduce it based on a fork of my stackblitz example please? (You could simulate http call with a `of({I don't know the input, is it a formgroup, or plain js object?}).pipe(delay(0))`

Answer (score 0):

I would manually trigger change detection using Angulars ChangeDetectorRef.

Inject it in your component and call detectChanges() whenever you update a form control.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

save(index: number) {
  console.log('save');
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```